# Не срабатывающий media запрос (или что-то другое)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, выравнивание

Есть код (файл tablet.css)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: (calc(39/768*100))%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: (calc(39/768*100))%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

.header > .header__text {
position: relative;
width: 93px;
height: 24px;
left: 0;
margin-top: 129px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

font-family: TT Norms;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 100%;
/* identical to box height, or 24px */


color: #000000;
}

/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/


.header__button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #5f3ec0;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1.75%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="globalcontainer">
                <div class="header">
                        <div class="header__text">
                            Обзоры
                        </div>
                        <div class="header__buttons">
                            <!-- <span> -->
                                <button class="header__button">Все</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Видео</button>               
                                <button class="header__button">Текст</button>               
                                <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
                                <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
                            <!-- </span> -->
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

А отображается как на скриншоте снизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где отступ `margin-left: (calc(39/768*100))%;`?

Comment: Начать стоит с того, что calc записан синтаксически некорректно

Comment: @andreymal а в чем заключается синтаксическая некорректность calc? (я сильно скурпулезно не рассматривал, но по моему ошибки нет)

Comment: @andreymal смотрел https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc()), но ошибки не нашел

Comment: @andreymal укажите в чем ошибка - для меня это очень важно.

Answer (score 2):

Данная подсказка должна помочь с `@media` запросами.

**Откройте вашу страницу в обычном браузере, нажмите правой кнопкой мыши и выберите "Просмотреть код" или "Инспектировать элемент"**

У вас откроется окно разработчика, в режиме онлайн. Там нажимайте на DIV классы (class) или id которые у вас криво отображаются и вам откроется CSS строка кода которая за это отвечает. Таким образом вы можете убирать какие-то пункты прямо в браузере друг за другом и смотреть что было сделано не так. Это увеличит скорость поиска ошибки. Такой подход будет сразу вам показывать где вы пропустили пункты, более того большинство браузеров показывают сами сразу где и каких пунктов не хватает в CSS.

Руководство по calc:   https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/493660